# Make array from a list and initialize it - Java

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have the following lists in a class

```
List<XYZ> Algo1;
List<XYZ> Algo2;
List<XYZ> Algo3;
```

and what I want is to create an array with these lists, try to do it like this:

```
List<XYZ> Algos[] = {Algo1,Algo2,Algo2};
```

I would like to be able to initialize it like that, but I get an error, the idea is to be able to call by means of a for and not individually

```
for(int i=0;i<Algos.length;i++){
    Algos[i].add(new XYZ(...));
}
```

Something like that, some idea?

Comment: Which error ? ^^

Comment: none in itself, just do not compile :v

Comment: Can you explain why you unaccepted?

Comment: @Sweeper porq that solution does not satiface completely the question, it must be with an `array` of type `List <XYZ>`, unless you say that this is not possible

Comment: @SamirLlorente it is impossible. Did you look at the link? It explains this very well.

Comment: @Sweeper ok, I had not seen it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**You cannot create arrays of parameterised types.**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays)

See the link for why.

Anyway, an alternative to this is to create a `List<List<XYZ>>`:

```
List<List<XYZ>> algoList = Arrays.asList(algo1, algo2, algo3);
```

Btw, remember to properly initialise algo 1-3 before putting them in a list! Otherwise you'll be putting nulls into a list!

If you want to add/remove stuff from `algoList`, you need an `ArrayList<List<Algo>>`:

```
ArrayList<List<XYZ>> algoList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(algo1, algo2, algo3));
```

Comment: you might also want to suggest `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(algo1, algo2, algo3))` if the OP wants the `algoList` to be mutable.

Comment: @Aominè Seeing how OP tried to create an array of lists, I assumed that OP does not intend to add/remove stuff, but good point anyway!

Comment: Instead of using another list, can not it be with an array?